# I need help starting my computer

Tags: grub2

I followed a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFvtU7R05wQ&list=PL77AAFB3B19CA924E) that told me how to uninstall Ubuntu after restarting the computer I received this message

```
Error: file not found.
grub rescue>
```

I have heard that you can reboot using a live CD, but mine is in a buddy's house and I have also heard that if you type `1s` it will do something. I have tried this and all I receive is:

```
 Unknown command '1s'
```

Comment: fyi, you aren't "uninstalling" rather "deleting" Ubuntu, and that you-tube video is not the proper way - he is a user that is purposefully  wanting to do harm to your system...

Comment: and say good bye to all your personal files, anything that was mounted is gone.

Comment: Did you read the title and about section of the video? He was *destroying* Ubuntu, not "uninstalling" it. You just deleted anything and everything you had mounted at the time, including your Ubuntu install. If you want to try to recover anything DON'T TOUCH THE MACHINE. Just leave it powered off until you decide how to proceed. More information about how your system was set up would be helpful, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is a video on how to *destroy* your Ubuntu installation, not remove it.

If you want to completely remove Ubuntu and switch to Windows, boot into a liveCD when you get one, read up on how to install Gparted, delete your primary Ubuntu partition(s), boot into a Windows OEM cd and use the command prompt to restore the NT bootloader grub replaced.

As for:

> Error: file not found. Grub rescue>

Grub is something called a bootloader. Bootloaders are used to bootstrap (initialize) Linux so that Ubuntu can run. Since Grub is a rather feature-rich bootloader, it holds most of it's code in your Ubuntu install. Since you *destroyed* your ubuntu install, grub can't find the rest of itself to load, and falls back to emergency console mode...

Also, since your tiny stage-1 grub install on the MBR most likely does not come with built-in NTFS support, you're out of luck if you want to boot back to windows without some sort of Rescue OS. Sorry :(